# How can I get "close friends" list of a Facebook user, using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

The graph Api gives me the user's friends.
But I want to know who its close friends are (SmartLists).

How can I do that using the Graph API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call [/me/friendlists](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friendlists) to get the friends list.  One of them should be close friends.  Then go to /closeFriendsListId/members to see who is on that list.  You will need read_friendlists extended permissions.

Comment: Does /me/friendslist require any extended permission?

Comment: Can you post the php script for get close friends list?

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me in JavaScript. I can access me/friendlists/close_friends but I can't access the members of the list.

Comment: /closeFriendListId/members won't work after graph API v1.0 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/friendlist/members?locale=en_GB

Answer (score 6):

I recently saw a simpler way. /me/friendlists/close_friends?fields=members will give you the list of all members at one shot. Just wanted to put it out here in case if somebody needs help.
Similarly, call to /me/friendlists/family?fields=members will give family members.
P.S: "close_friends" and "family" are keywords and no need for a ID.

Comment: This works in Graph Explorer, but I'm not sure how to display the members in JavaScript. Alert(response) will just display [object object].

Comment: Uh, alert(JSON.stringify(response)) or console.log should do?

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer possible.  Facebook removed the ability to see the members of a friend list somewhere before version 2.5 of their API.